# Can we use Google Cloud Drive Storage instead Google cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

We are using Google Cloud Storage to Store the Video/Audios/images files on the cloud. We want to use Google G Suite drive to Store the data. Can we use Google Drive instead of Cloud storage, then what will be the complications?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Storage is for serving website content, storing data for archival.
G Suit is designed for business, online storage, Easy data migration.
Google Drive is a file storage and synchronization service developed, allows users to store files on their servers, synchronize files across devices, and share files.

Depends the application that you need for your files, your Team Members or maybe coulbe be for personal use.